# MVC dynamically "expanding" @Html.EditorFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller, client-side

Suppose I have a model with some string property.

Imagine also that this string property is actually a comma delimited list of values.

If I want to make a form to update values on my model it would be easy enough to call:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myCommaDelimitedProp, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "CommaDelimitedPropValue" })
```

However, that is not good enough for the intended application.

I would like to have a custom EditorFor() that could somehow take my property, use string parsing and next generate an array of text boxes to display the pre-existing values.

That would also be relatively trivial.

However, what I cannot seem to solve, mainly because I lack client side experience (js, jquery, angular, ...):

How could I make my editor such that there would be a small button so that I could dynamically add rows, fill them such that, upon form submission, I could string the new values onto the pre-existing  string.

So specifically, what would any of you use to achieve this client side behaviour?

I just need some help to be put on the way...

Comment: Knockout MVC: http://knockoutmvc.com/ContactsEditor seems to offer functionality that I would need but I'm holding off on considering this a real solution until I learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with editor templates. There's a [quick intro I threw together on my blog](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/). The only additional thing you'll need is `UIHint`. Since you won't be able to rely on a specific C# type or `DataType` annotation to determine that this should be treated as a comma-delimited property. You can just explicitly tell Razor what template it should use. For example:

```
[UIHint("CommaDelimited")]
public string MyCommaDelimitedProperty { get; set; }
```

Which would correspond to the editor template: `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\CommaDelimited.cshtml`. Once you set up that view how you like it. Then in your form you just call:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyCommaDelimitedProperty)
```

**EDIT**

I'll leave my previous answer because it could still be helpful in terms of being able to generate a control for a specific type of thing. You actually may still need to use it to get the right set up on your field to make the JS work properly.

However, when it comes to the client-side handling of this, I figured there had to be something out there already to solve this problem. (Never do more work than you have to.) A cursory search turned up a little script called [Tokenfield for Bootstrap](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/). I'm not sure if you're using Bootstrap or not. If not, I also found [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and [jquery.token-field](http://sbfaulkner.github.io/jquery.token-field/demo.html). I'm sure there's others, as well.

Comment: thanks already for this answer. I was actually unaware of UIHint so I already learnt something there. Also, I am indeed using bootstrap and Tokenfield indeed does something similar to what I would want but in may case, I' d like users to be able to amend position entries to  their CV so Ideally I' d want something similar to a Tokenfield but more suited for a CV entry, ie an expanding list of text boxes or something. Token field seems more suited for tagging. But again, thanks already!